# TypeError: this.state.news.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

On trying to get data from the api using axios and iam getting the error below : TypeError: this.state.news.map is not a function.

on console.log i am getting the data as an array.

```
state = {
    news : []
}

componentDidMount() {
    const url = `${API_URL}`;
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
     this.setState({ news: data })
       console.log(this.state.news)
     })
  }


  render (){
  return (
    <div className="container">
     <div className="col-xs-8">
      {this.state.news.map((newsItem) => (
       <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{newsItem.name}</h5>
           <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
           {newsItem.title}             
           </h6>
         </div>
       </div>
     ))}
     </div>
    </div>
 );
     }
```

**Below is the screenshot of my console.log**

[image: console.log screenshot]

Comment: When you do a console.log() immediately after using this.setState(), you're very likely to still get an empty array, because the console.log() executes before the completed request. Can you verify what what the returned data looks like from the API before callings setState()?

Comment: Thank you. I have added console.log screenshot. this.state.news is an array

Comment: @ChristopherNgo `console.log` will execute when the request is completed since it's inside of the `then(...)` call... the issue is that `this.setState` is not synchronous, so if you want to read the actual/new state, you should do `this.setState({ news: data }, () => { console.log('new state', this.state) })`...

Comment: @MkhululiCooperNcubeKamzilan if `console.log(this.state.news)` prints out an object that looks like this - `{status: "ok", totalResults: 7194, articles: Array(20)}` - then you're updating your state with that object, and not with the `articles` array... You need to do `this.setState({ news: data.articles })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a conditional check to verify that `this.state.news` is in fact an array before executing the `.map()`

```
render(){
  return (
    <div className="container">
     <div className="col-xs-8">
      {Array.isArray(this.state.news) ? this.state.news.map((newsItem) => (
       <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
           <h5 className="card-title">{newsItem.name}</h5>
           <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">
           {newsItem.title}             
           </h6>
         </div>
       </div>
      )) : (
       "No news found"
      )}
     </div>
    </div>
 );
}
```

You should also verify that the data returned from your API via the `componentDidMount` logic is in-fact in array. With axios, the response from the API is stored in an object. The object has a key called `data`, which likely includes the `array` you're looking for.

### Edit:

With the screenshot you posted, it looks like my theory was right. You have to go one level more to access the articles array in your response object. Simply do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const url = `${API_URL}`;
    axios.get(url)
       .then((res) => {
           this.setState({
              news: res.data.articles
          })
       })
       .catch((errors) => {
           this.setState({
              errors: errors.response.data
           })
       })
}
```

My theory is that you need to one level lower in the data object to extra the array you're looking for.

Comment: You can call `map` on an empty array, you just won't see any items rendered. The check should be to see if `this.state.news` is an array - `Array.isArray(this.state.news)` - and then displaying a fallback based on this check. Otherwise, this will keep complaining.

Comment: @goto1 thanks,  I was in the middle of writing that :)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I have console.log screenshot. on the question this.state.news is an array.

Comment: @MkhululiCooperNcubeKamzilan I took a look at your updated question. It looks like you're updating the state with an object, not an array. With that said, can you try my updated solution and let me know if that works.

Answer (score 1):

console.log(this.state.news) returns {status: "ok", totalResults: 7194, articles: Array(20)}. So it means data isn't array and only data.articles is array.
So you should set the state like this.

```
this.setState({ news: data.articles });
```

And also you should check the the news before using it.

```
this.state.news && this.state.news.map(...)
```